# enormously use of /var folder in ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hi I have a Ubuntu server running Virtualmin and it's a dedicated web server. But the problem is with the /var directory which is on a separate partition of 7 GB and is now full. But when I run the comand:

```
df -h /var
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7  7.4G 6.6G 379M  95%  /var
```

and when i run the command:

```
du -ch var/
 793M total
```

How I can clean this directory so it won't take so much space?

Comment: Take a look at the answers here http://serverfault.com/questions/485483/root-full-linux-no-free-blocks/485495#485495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a file in /var that's been deleted but is still open. As such it can't appear in the usage stats from `du`, but it still takes space on the disk until it's closed.

You can use the `lsof` command to find open files in /var - `sudo lsof -n | egrep "/var/" | sort -n -k5` to get the largest open files in /var at the bottom of the list, and what program has it open.

Answer (score 0):

You can cd to /var  and run du -sh * which will give you the usage of directory in /var partition.

Comment: `du -sh *
1.5M    backups
43M     cache
4.0K    crash
454M    lib
4.0K    local
0       lock
24M     log
16K     lost+found
4.0K    mail
4.0K    opt
92K     run
24M     spool
4.0K    tmp
44K     usermin
67M     webmin
196K    www`