# Var folder maxing out /dev/mapper/vg00-var

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-machines, tmp, var

Over the past few years we have had multiple linux servers have the same problem time and time again, our /dev/mapper/vg00-var folder max out at 100%. which means all sites on the server die.

We have found a temporary solution for this which is to increase the size of this var folder, however we keep increasing the size of this folder it keeps filling up, we have had one server maxing out even though the folder size is very large.

Is there a way of emptying this folder, as it is eating into our server capacity regularly. Also what are the files that are being saved here? are they needed? is there a way of preventing so much data getting stored here?

We are running a cms site on the server called concrete5.

Answer (score 1):

The [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) utility is likely [your friend](https://serverfault.com/search?q=logrotate).

The [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) utility may be [useful too](https://serverfault.com/questions/485483/root-full-linux-no-free-blocks/485495#485495).

Believe it or not the search facility here on SF is [helpful as well](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%2Fvar%20full).